# Condtionally assign a value

Tags: php, variables

I have this function:

```
function my_function($value1, $value2, $value3 = null){
    if($value1 || $value2 || $value3 == 'my_title' ){
        echo '<title>'.$value2.'</title>';
    }
}

my_function('my_css', 'my_title');
```

So as you can see I had to put in the echo $value2 becuase I cannot figure out how I would be able to use either $value 1,2 or 3. I was thinking this could be solved by doing something like this:

```
  if($value1 || $value2 || $value3 == 'my_title' $title = $value1 || $value2 || $value3 ){
```

Is this possible?

I hope you can understand what im trying to achieve here.

---------------------------------------------------- SOLVED --------------------------------------------------------

Thanks to rohitarora for the best answer for this question.

i would like to share with everyone what you have helped me make.

if you have this function

```
function template_content($value1, $value2, $value3 = null){ global $title;
$value = array($value1, $value2, $value3);
for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++)
{
    if (strpos($value[$i],'title: ') === 0 ){
        $title = explode("title: ",$value[$i]);
        echo "\t", '<title>'.$title[1].'</title>', "\n";
    } else if (strpos($value[$i],'css: ') === 0 ){
        $css = explode("css: ",$value[$i]);
        echo "\t", '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$css[1].'">', "\n";
    } else if (strpos($value[$i],'js: ') === 0 ){
        $js = explode("js: ",$value[$i]);
        echo "\t", '<script src="'.$js[1].'"></script>', "\n";
    }
}

}
```

you can call this function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php template_content('css: http://google.com/style.css', 'title: hello', 'js: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'); ?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and you will get this amazing result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://google.com/style.css">
    <title>hello</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ehm this code doesn't make much sense. Why dont you just write echo '<title>my_title</title>'; ? :)

Comment: Because im making a templating system so the title is never going to be my_title and if i done that the function would never know what the title is if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function my_function($value1, $value2, $value3 = null) {
    // make a array of all your values
    $title = array($value1, $value2, $value3);
    // for loop will run as the size of array like here there are three element in array value1,2,3
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($title); $i++)
    {
        // check if the string is there in the ith element in array
        if ($title[$i] == 'my_title')
        {
            echo '<title>'.$title[$i].'</title>';
        }
    }
}

my_function('my_css', 'my_title');
```

Do it in array, that's a better way.

Comment: Well thank you rohitarora, that was the answer i was looking for. great :) if you wish to help more, you could explain what the for does as i am confused by it, but never the less this is my answer its up to you. Thanks

Comment: i have edited my answer hope it will explain you a litle sorry for not explaing before.

Comment: Thanks very much i have put the function in my original question if it is handy to you

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'my_title';

switch ($string) {
     case $value1 :         $title = $value1;         break;
     case $value2 :         $title = $value2;         break;
     case $value3 :         $title = $value3;         break;
}

echo '<title>'.$title.'</title>';
```

This is what you need :)

Comment: Ok. cool. well as i'm not a pro at php i wouldn't know how to implement this into a if statement? can you help. Please? im glad there is a solution though.

Comment: This is an if statement, only better :). you can delete your if statement and implement this instead.

Comment: Why do you need an if statement? A switch-case block is way better for this situations

Comment: like i said i didnt know a switch was a type if statement

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_function (){
    $args = func_get_args();

    foreach ($args as $arg){
        echo '<title>'.$arg.'</title>';
    }
}

my_function('my_css', 'my_title');
```

This function can take any number of params you give it, and will print every one inside  tags

Comment: Thanks for taking you time to answer but just to let you know this outputs the title as my_css, that is not what im looking for if this was to work it would output my_title as the title

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
if ($value1 || $value2 || $value3 == 'my_title') {
     // Some code
}
```

does not return the result that you might think it will: it is evaluated as follows: if *either* `$value1` is `true` (it is evaluated as it were a boolean), *or* `$value2` is `true`, *or* `$value3` equals `my_title`, then execute some code.

If you want to use either `$value1`, `$value2` or `$value3` when it equals `my_title`, use the following:

```
function my_function($value1, $value2, $value3 = null) {
    $searchStr = "my_title";
    $r = "";
    switch ($searchStr) {
        case $value1:
            $r = $value1;
            break;
        case $value2:
            $r = $value2;
            break;
        case $value3:
            $r = $value3;
            break;
    }
    echo '<title>'.$r.'</title>';
}
```

If you are allergic for switch statements (well, you really shouldn't!), then use this:

```
function my_function($value1, $value2, $value3 = null) {
    $searchStr = "my_title";
    $r = "";
    if ($value1 == $searchStr) {
        $r = $value1;
    }
    else if ($value2 == $searchStr) {
        $r = $value2;
    }
    else if ($value3 == $searchStr) {
        $r = $value3;
    }
    echo '<title>'.$r.'</title>';
}
```

Notice that it's better to return the result of a function rather than echoing it instantly.

Comment: Talking of return if i have this return "\t", '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$css[1].'">', "\n"; it outputs error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\Server\www\hidie\libs\test.php on line 22

Comment: @ConnorMiles `return` does not take parameters separated with a comma, so `return "string", "another string";` does not work. A function can only return one result.
I think you mean to concatenate the strings with the dot (`.`) operator, returning `"\t"."<link... />"."\n"`.

I suggest you to have another look at the PHP syntax, and read some more. (http://php.about.com/od/phpfunctions/PHP_Functions.htm)

Comment: I know it doesn't work that's why I asked, so Realy it is better for me to use echo right?